# Prepend message body with warning text on Postfix?

Tags: postfix

Due to internal policy, we need to prepend each external mail message with some text like "This is external message, please be careful". We're with Postfix now, so seems I need some extra software to do that job on each message. Please advice, how can I do that!

The problem is, message can contain more that just plain text body, moreover, each MIME part can be plaintext or html/richtext, and each such part should be prepended differently.

Another question can me very similar: as more and more phishing messages are coming in, I'd like to modify links in each message so link can be controlled with our own server: say, if there is a link to "http://www.site.com" then I'd modify it to point to "https://our.own.server.local/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com" (you got the idea), so on our server our.own.server.local I can block further opening the link if necessary. Is it possible to do, please advice!

Comment: You can do at least some of what you want with [MIMEDefang](https://mimedefang.org/).   IMO, it's not worth the bother (because warning people who don't know not to click on links will not stop them from clicking on the links anyway) - just 5xx reject spam or configure postfix to use [amavisd](https://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/) and quarantine it.

Comment: @cas, I agree with you that user can hurt himself even if you stand by him/her and warning him/her aloud not to click on anything... But this is some legally required thing so users won't be able to tell they wasn't warned.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is now a bit stale, but I think it's important to leave this hint to those coming after me:

**DO NOT TOUCH THE MAIL BODY!**

This breaks all cryptographic signatures and thus should *never* be done. Instead, prepend it to the Subject-header.

Comment: I wasn't ctear in my question, the problem is to mark each *incoming* message with the the text line in the body so person who rad the message will be notified that this is external message and it is dangerous to open lins in it.